# ошибка метода asigin()

Tags: yii2

Пытаюсь реализовать изменение ролей пользователя следующим образом
Вот контролер:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $auth=Yii::$app->getAuthManager();
        $post=Yii::$app->request->post();
        $role=$auth->getRole($post[role]);
        $auth->assign($role->name,$id);
        $model->save();
       return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
            'auth'  =>Yii::$app->authManager->roles,
        ]);
    }
}
```

выдает такую ошибку

```
Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'item_name' cannot be null
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `auth_assignment` (`user_id`, `item_name`, `created_at`) VALUES ('2', NULL, 1453126363)
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23000
    [1] => 1048
    [2] => Column 'item_name' cannot be null
)
Caused by: PDOException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'item_name' cannot be null
in E:\serv\OpenServer\domains\crimea\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Command.php at line 781
```

точно знаю что сюда передается 'moderator' почему возникает такая ошибка не подскажете? По документации я вижу что в asign() передается роль yii\rbac\Role подскажите что туда передать

Comment: Прям точно при точно?)) может в `$post[role]` должны быть ковычки типа `$post['role']` ?

Comment: вроде так и так делал сейчас проверю.

Comment: Лучше сделать `print_r($role); die();` и убедиться точно, что данные имеются

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я var_dump проверял и сушествено ни чего не меняеться от кавычек.

Comment: чую что надо писать минимум `$post['User']['role']`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский  теперь bad request (#400)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а var_dump возращает null тогда как $post['role'] или $post[role] возращает moderator

Comment: На счет вопроса про документацию - очевидно в assign() должен идти сам объект $role, а не $role->name...

Comment: @kroder ты прав.. только что сам хотел написать об этом

Comment: @Sergalas В итоге вам надо 1) передавать не `$post[role]`, а все таки `$post['User']['role']` и 2) не `$auth->assign($role->name,$id);` а `$auth->assign($role, $id);` причем `assign` вообще лучше делать после условия `if ($model->save())`

Comment: У меня такая мысль первая возникла когда увидел что должно получать  yii\rbac\Role я попытался сделать так но assign проходит но изменений ни каких в базе не происходит.

Comment: Дак все еще не получается что-ли? А роль такая точно вообще присутствует в рбаке? Вам по сути нужно просто пораспечатывать последовательно все один раз. Посмотрели, что в $post['role'] - если там имя нужной роли, то дальше посмотрели чего оказалось в $role после getRole(), если там null, то в рбаке такой роли нет и копать надо не здесь.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ошибка снова появилась

Comment: @kroder   $role = $auth->getRole($post['role']); выдает object(yii\rbac\Role)#100 (7) { ["type"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(10) " moderator" ["description"]=> string(9) "Moderator" ["ruleName"]=> string(5) "group" ["data"]=> NULL ["createdAt"]=> string(10) "1453060942" ["updatedAt"]=> string(10) "1453060942" }

Comment: @Sergalas ошибка может появляться потому что уже один раз добавили юзера в `auth_assignment` и он там уже есть...............у модератора опять пробелы в начале

Comment: Дак а щас какая ошибка? Я потерялся немного)

Comment: @krober если писать так $role = $auth->getRole($post['role']); $model->save(); $auth->assign($role, $id); ошибки нет но ни чего не изменяется роль условно "модератора" не присваевается. По другому вываливается ошибка та что я писал.

Comment: Если ничего не меняется, то предлагаю открыть бд и посмотреть содержимое auth_ таблиц, вполне может что-то прояснить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский кстати да, там должно выкинуться исключение, если роль уже была у юзера, так что надо еще revoke/revokeAll перед assign() не забывать, или оборачивать. Но это напосле. )

Comment: @kroder про revoke вы правы оформляйте ответ я прийму все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По итогу внушительной переписки можно резюмировать следующее:

- в $auth->assign() должен идти объект $role, а не имя роли
- перед assign() нужно или удалить возможный дубликат выставляемой роли через revoke/revokeAll, или оборачивать и ловить возможное исключение
- на счет заморочек с $post[role] я чесно так и не понял что там было, но видимо все нормально

Comment: Ну по идее все равно должно быть  `$post['User']['role']` )) ибо передается через `post` модель с аттрибутами. А это массив. А если и будет работать `$post[role]` то недолго. в конечном итоге всплывет ошибка))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я так понял во вьюхе поле роли вписано вне модели User как раз, просто свое доп поле идет с запросом, раз все работает.